# Shopware database credentials

Tags: shopware

I am using 6.4.1.2 Stable Version of Shopware. I have the FTP and database URL. How do I know that where are the database details? I have tried the .env file, but the database details are not there. Kindly help.

Comment: Normally you can find the credentials in the `.env` file in variables `DATABASE_USER` and `DATABASE_PASSWORD`.

Answer (score 1):

I‘m not quite sure whether I understood your Question correctly. What I think you want to do is to get the MySQL credentials from your .env.

You can find these credentials in the database URL which looks like this:

DATABASE_URL=mysql://username:password@localhost:3306/dbname

Comment: If you can't find your `.env` file, you can run `php bin/console debug:dotenv` to get it from the command line.